# Magento2 Development - System Requirements

Tags: magento2, phpstorm

Hi Magento2 Developers,

In your experience, what are the **system requirements** (cpu, ram, etc...) for a fully featured **development machine** and what **softwares** are you using?

"fully featured" meaning:

- Source-Code Indexing (incl. dependencies)
- Code-Competition (incl. dependencies)
- Code-Inspections
- XDebug
- *and every other feature required in daily work*

I am running a **Linux Desktop** (xfce), Ide (PhpStorm) & Browser (Chrome) on my development machine with an **Intel E3-CPU** and **8GB Ram**.

In my experience it would need at least 16GB Ram to run without swapping like crazy.

Comment: It depends on how many magento 2 projects will have open at the same time. I currently have 16gb ram + i7 processor + 512ssd and Magento2 runs smoothly over LAMP. I usually have 4 or 5 magento2 projects open in phpstorm at the same time. Chrome is one of the most memory eater in my pc.

Comment: Did you find what you are looking for?

Comment: no i realized that the setup is way to diverse to draw any conclusions

Answer (score 0):

I have core i7, 7th generation laptop with 8 GB RAM.

8 GB is enough for development machine (But the more you put the more its good)

CPU speed and RAM is enough for your system. But the main thing is your **hard disk read write speed**. You will need a good hard disk speed to run Magento on your local system.

And for **PHPStorm**: I am currently using it, this is best editor that I have ever used. But them main issue of magento development on PHPstorm is: When you apply `upgrad, static deploy etc` **PHPStorm continuously runs code indexing**, your deployment script took changes code and PHPStorm index it in parallel. **So, all you need to do is :** Stop PHPStorm indexing process and then while executing shell commands, your shell commands will run better than before.

Hope you find your answer :)